# How to apply a custom Monad Transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Say I have some Monadic type

```
data Example a = CheckIt {unwrap :: a}

instance Functor Example where
  fmap f (CheckIt x) = CheckIt (f x)

instance Applicative Example where
  pure = CheckIt
  CheckIt f <*> CheckIt x = CheckIt (f x)

instance Monad (Example) where
  return = CheckIt
  e@(CheckIt a) >>= f = f a
```

and I have a function which returns an `[a]` based on some input:

```
fetchList :: b -> [Int]
fetchList _ = [1,2,3,4]
```

and a function that returns an IO [a] (simplified from real implementation):

```
basicIoWrap :: [a] -> IO [a]
basicIoWrap x = return x
```

and I wish to run this IO and then extract an Example [a] from it:

The following does not work:

```
 foo :: b -> Example [a]
 foo val = (basicIoWrap (fetchList val)) >>= \list -> return list
```

complaining about different monad types

```
 Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘Example’
      Expected type: Example [a]
        Actual type: IO [Int]
```

So I understand that this is exactly the usecase for Monad transformers, but I am really struggling figuring out how to apply them in context. Say I had a transformer:

```
newtype ExampleT m a = ExampleT {runExampleT :: m (Example a)}
```

and I rephrased my signature to 
   foo :: b -> ExampleT (IO [a])

I am unclear what the function body would then look like, and also, how I would eventually extract an Example [a] from this? Wouldn't `runExampleT ExampleT (IO [a])` give an `IO [Example a]`, thus simply punting the multi Monad problem further down the road?

Comment: Short of various unsafe "escape" functions, you can't remove the list from the IO monad to return an `Example [a]`. The reason there is no `IoT` transformer is because the IO monad, if used, must be at the base of the stack, meaning the outer most monad of any stack is `IO`.

Comment: so then how is this kind of situation generally handled?

Comment: A monad transformer is primarily about adding behavior to an existing monad, not extracting values from it. If `foo` returns an `IO (Example [a])` (as @user2297560 beat me to suggesting), then it is relatively easy to write a function with type `bar :: Example [a] -> IO [a]` to retrieve the inner list (while keeping it in an IO context). With such a function, you can then write `foo >>= bar`.

Answer (score 2):

You can never safely "escape" from `IO`, but if you have a value of a type like `Example (IO [a])` and `Example` is at least a `Traversable`, then you can turn it into `IO (Example [a])` with the `sequence` function. Using this method you could write your `foo` function as:

```
foo :: b -> IO (Example [a])
foo = sequence . return . basicIoWrap . fetchList
```

Since you must already be working in the `IO` monad in order to use `basicIoWrap`, you can access the `Example [a]`. For example:

```
do input <- getLine
   (Example as) <- foo input
   mapM_ print as
```

Comment: Note that `Example` needs a `Traversable` instance in order for `sequence` to turn the `Example (IO [a])` value into a `IO (Example [a])` value.